# What is best practice to remove duplicate/redundant API requests?

Tags: javascript, react-redux, redux-thunk

So I am working in a React platform that has data that updates every second(I would like to move to web-sockets but its currently only supports gets).Currently, each  component makes a fetch request for itself to get the data for the widget. Because the fetch requests are built into the widgets there are redundant api requests for the same data. I am looking for a possible better solution to remove these redundant api requests.

The solution I came up with uses what I call a data service that checks for any subscription to data sources then makes those api calls and places the data in a redux state for the components to then be used. I am unsure if this is the best way to go about handling the issue I am trying to avoid. I don't like how I need an interval to be run every second the app is running to check if there are "subscriptions". I am unsure if thats the correct way to go about it. With this solution I don't duplicate any requests and can add or remove a subscription without affecting other components.

One more thing, the id can change and will change what data I recieve

Here is a simplified version of how I am handling the service.

```
const reduxState = {
 id: "specific-id",  
 subscriptions: {
    sourceOne: ["source-1-id-1", "source-1-id-2", "source-1-id-3"],
    sourceTwo: ["source-2-id-1", "source-one-id-2"],
  },
  data: {
    sourceOne: { id: "specific-id", time: "milliseconds", data: "apidata" },
    sourceTwo: { id: "specific-id", time: "milliseconds", data: "apidata" },
  },
};

const getState = () => reduxState; //Would be a dispatch to always get current redux state

const dataService = () => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    const state = getState();
    if (state.subscriptions.sourceOne.length > 0)
      fetchSourcOneAndStoreInRedux();
    if (state.subscriptions.sourceTwo.length > 0)
      fetchSourceTwoAndStoreInRedux();
  }, 1000);
};

const fetchSourcOneAndStoreInRedux = (id) =>{
    return async dispatch => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(`/data/one/${id}`) 
            dispatch(setSourceOneDataRedux(res.data))
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err)
        }
    }
}
```

I am building my components to only show data from the correct id.

Comment: I think you are on the right track here. Basically, if you have a bunch of shared state across components, it's the right idea to have a higher level data model fetch the data and set it in an observable store that can be accessed by all the components sharing the same data. Those components will automatically react to the observable state changes and re-render accordingly. The components themselves shouldn't be calling functions to fetch API data, let the higher level data model do that and manage it. I realize it's pseudo code but I think there is some definite room for improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if you have any references on where to go for some examples to improve the base concept I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I put together what I am calling a data manger for demo purposes below. Hopefully the explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple working example of a simple "DataManager" that would achieve what you are looking for.

```js
class DataManager {
  constructor(config = {}) {
    this.config = config;
    console.log(`DataManager: Endpoint "${this.config.endpoint}" initialized.`);
    if (this.config.autostart) { // Autostart the manager if autostart property is true
      this.start();
    }
  }

  config; // The config object passed to the constructor when initialized
  fetchInterval; // The reference to the interval function that fetches the data
  data; // Make sure you make this state object observable via MOBX, Redux etc so your component will re-render when data changes.
  fetching = false; // Boolean indicating if the APIManager is in the process of fetching data (prevent overlapping requests if response is slow from server)

  // Can be used to update the frequency the data is being fetched after the class has been instantiated
  // If interval already has been started, stop it and update it with the new interval frequency and start the interval again
  updateInterval = (ms) => {
    if (this.fetchInterval) {
      this.stop();
      console.log(`DataManager: Updating interval to ${ms} for endpoint ${this.config.endpoint}.`);
      this.config.interval = ms;
      this.start();
    } else {
      this.config.interval = ms;
    }
    return this;
  }

  // Start the interval function that polls the endpoint
  start = () => {
    if (this.fetchInterval) {
      clearInterval(this.fetchInterval);
      console.log(`DataManager: Already running! Clearing interval so it can be restarted.`);
    }

    this.fetchInterval = setInterval(async () => {
      if (!this.fetching) {
        console.log(`DataManager: Fetching data for endpoint "${this.config.endpoint}".`);
        this.fetching = true;
        // const res = await axios.get(this.config.endpoint); 
        // Commented out for demo purposes but you would uncomment this and clear the anonymous function below
        const res = {};
        (() => {
          res.data = {
            dataProp1: 1234,
            dataProp2: 4567
          }
        })();
        this.fetching = false;
        this.data = res.data;
      } else {
        console.log(`DataManager: Waiting for pending response for endpoint "${this.config.endpoint}".`);
      }
    }, this.config.interval);

    return this;
  }

  // Stop the interval function that polls the endpoint
  stop = () => {
    if (this.fetchInterval) {
      clearInterval(this.fetchInterval);
      console.log(`DataManager: Endpoint "${this.config.endpoint}" stopped.`);
    } else {
      console.log(`DataManager: Nothing to stop for endpoint "${this.config.endpoint}".`);
    }
    return this;
  }

}

const SharedComponentState = {
  source1: new DataManager({
    interval: 1000,
    endpoint: `/data/one/someId`,
    autostart: true
  }),
  source2: new DataManager({
    interval: 5000,
    endpoint: `/data/two/someId`,
    autostart: true
  }),
  source3: new DataManager({
    interval: 10000,
    endpoint: `/data/three/someId`,
    autostart: true
  })
};

setTimeout(() => { // For Demo Purposes, Stopping and starting DataManager.
  SharedComponentState.source1.stop();
  SharedComponentState.source1.updateInterval(2000);
  SharedComponentState.source1.start();
}, 10000);

// Heres what it would look like to access the DataManager data (fetched from the api)
// You will need to make sure you pass the SharedComponentState object as a prop to the components or use another React mechanism for making that SharedComponentState accessible to the components in your app
// Accessing state for source 1: SharedComponentState.source1.data
// Accessing state for source 2: SharedComponentState.source2.data
// Accessing state for source 3: SharedComponentState.source3.data
```

Basically, each instance of the DataManager class is responsible for fetching a different api endpoint. I included a few other class methods that allow you to start, stop and update the polling frequency of the DataManager instance.

Comment: This is awesome and makes a-lot of sense. Thinking of implementing something similar. But with the the class keeping track of which components tell it to start and stop and only stop when all components have signed off.  Very much appreciated.